# jEdit - how to close a pane?

Tags: text-editors, jedit

I have jEdit window split into two panes (which can display different files).

I want to close one of the panes ("unsplit" the window).

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source [Chapter 3. jEdit Basics - Multiple Views](http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/views.html)

> View>Unsplit Current (shortcut: C+0) removes the split containing the
>   current TextArea only.
>
> View>Unsplit All (shortcut: C+1) removes all splits from the View.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with "Unsplit All" button in the toolbar.